# Retrieve value from checkbox

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have jsp code like this

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.XX}" var="x">
   <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="${x.xID}" name="x"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;${x.name}</td>
   </tr>    
</c:forEach>
```

I am not able to retrieve value of checkbox in servlets.
My servlet code is here :

```
String  xId=request.getParameter("x");
```

May i know where i am going wrong?
Requirement is that only one checkbox is checked. So no need of array in servlets

Comment: If you have a _requirement_ that the user checks only one checkbox, then you're using the wrong UI element. You need to use radio buttons. Checkboxes are for (de)selecting items independently of each other; radio buttons are for selecting one choice among many.

Answer (score 3):

does it shows more than one checkbox with name `x` ? as it is in c:forEach if so then

```
String xId=request.getParameter("x");
```

will take value of first checkbox every time.

Comment: Yes there are many checkboxes as they are in for loop. But it doesnt take even value of first checkbox

Comment: so try to add some index to the name so that at the time of retrieval you can achieve unique one

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()` instead.

```
String[] checked = request.getParameterValues("x");
// ...
```